# pubpspect get failed when adding flutter_html lib in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-html

I have tried to build app 'flutter_html: ^2.1.5" but I unable to build and getting below error in log.

```
 The current Flutter SDK version is 1.27.0-2.0.pre.1.

Because flutter_app depends on flutter_html >=2.1.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=2.2.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because flutter_app depends on flutter_html >=2.1.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=2.2.0, version solving failed.)
```

can you suggest the way to clear this issue?

---

I have upgraded flutter version  and migrated and having different issue.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:checkDebugManifest' (type 'CheckManifest').
  - In plugin 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin' type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckManifest' property 'manifest' has @Input annotation used on property of type 'File'.

    Reason: A property of type 'File' annotated with @Input cannot determine how to interpret the file.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Annotate with @InputFile for regular files.
      2. Annotate with @InputDirectory for directories.
      3. If you want to track the path, return File.absolutePath as a String and keep @Input.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#incorrect_use_of_input_annotation for more details about this problem.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: you can try without version `flutter_html:` or `flutter_html: ^1.3.0`

Comment: can you edit with flutter doctor in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade your flutter SDK. Write `flutter upgrade` in terminal.

Or use an older version of `flutter_html`.

Comment: can you check my question and I have updated

Comment: That is gradle error. I don't know much about. I recommend marking this as answered an create a new question with a gradle tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to pubspec.yaml flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.3.